# C++11 VS12 regex_search

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I'm trying to retrieve numbers from string. String format like `_0_1_` and I want to get `0` and `1`.

Here is my code:

```
std::tr1::regex rx("_(\\d+)_");
tstring fileName = Utils::extractFileName(docList[i]->c_str());                 
std::tr1::smatch res;
std::tr1::regex_search(fileName, res, rx);
```

but at the result I have (UPDATED: this is strange outputs from debugger watch):

```
res[0] = 3
res[1] = 1
```

Where `3` came from and what I'm doing wrong?

UPDATED:
I output results to the screen:

```
for (std::tr1::smatch::iterator it = res.begin(); it < res.end(); ++it){
    std::cout << *it << std::endl;
}
```

And programm output:

```
_0_
0
```

Comment: I'm afraid we're gonna need more information - e.g. how you produce this output

Comment: Can you show how you check the results? BTW, `res[0]` will return the *entire matched expression,* not the first subexpression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:
Thx to all, rewrite with help of `regex_token_iterator` and `(\\d+)`. Now it works:

```
std::regex_token_iterator<tstring::iterator> rend;
tstring fileName = Utils::extractFileName(docList[i]->c_str());                   
std::tr1::regex_search(fileName, res, rx);              
for (std::regex_token_iterator<std::string::iterator> it(fileName.begin(), fileName.end(), rx); it != rend; ++it) {
        std::cout << " [" << *it << "]";
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A regexp normally returns all **non-overlapping** matches, so if you add `_` both in front and on the back of numbers you're not going to get all the numbers because the underscore **after** the first number cannot be used to match also as the underscore **before** the second number

```
_123_456_
    ^
    This cannot be used twice
```

Just use `(\\d+)` as expression to get all numbers (regexp is "greedy" by default so all the available digits will be found anyway).

Comment: Of course it does, but only because that is how a regular expression match is described. The first match is the *entire matching substring* and the second and subsequent are your capture groups (if any).

Comment: Plus you'll have to repeat the call to regex_search.

Answer (score 2):

This appears to be the expected output. The first match should be the entire substring which matched, and then the second (and so forth) should be the capture groups.

If you'd like to go through all matches, you'll need to call `regex_search` multiple times to get each match:

```
auto it = fileName.cbegin();
while (std::tr1::regex_search(it, fileName.cend(), res, rx)) {
    std::cout << "Found matching group:" << std::endl;
    for (int mm = 1; mm < res.size(); ++mm) {
        std::cout << std::string(res[mm].first, res[mm].second) << std::endl;
    }

    it = res[0].second; // start 1 past the end
}
```

If you do really need only the numbers "wrapped" in underscores, you can use a positive assertion `(?=_)` to ensure this occurs:

```
// positive assertions are required matches, but are not consumed by the
// matching group.
std::tr1::regex rx("_(\\d+)(?=_)");
```

Which, when run against `"//abc_1_2_3.txt"`, retrieves 1 and 2, but not 3.